# How to get the values from a nested array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array in Angular called testUsers with the following sample data:

```
this.testUsers = [
    {email: '1@fake.com', name: 'A Smith'}
    {email: '2@fake.com', name: 'B Johnson'}
    {email: '3@fake.com', name: 'C Dobbs', colours: 
      ['green', 'blue', red']
    }
    {email: '4@fake.com', name: 'D Mew', colours: 
      ['black', 'blue']
    }
]
```

What I need is to get the values inside the nested 'colours' array in a new array.
Best I can get is to end up with a value as [Array(1)] which then contains data.  But I need the values, not the values as an array.

How do I fix this function?

```
this.newArray = this.testUsers.map(value => {
  return value.colours
});
```

Comment: How do you want the values explicitly? The map method is the best way. Then you can get all colors with a for loop.

Comment: Ideally I would like the values as this.newArray=['green', 'blue', red'] if for example filtering on email for 3@fake.com.  I will probably be doing user filtering up front so I might not need to combine nested arrays.

Comment: Nina has just solved it for me, thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a flat array as result with a default value for not given property.

```js
const
    testUsers = [{ email: '1@fake.com', name: 'A Smith' }, { email: '2@fake.com', name: 'B Johnson' }, { email: '3@fake.com', name: 'C Dobbs', colours: ['green', 'blue', 'red'] }, { email: '4@fake.com', name: 'D Mew', colours: ['black', 'blue'] }],
    colours = testUsers.flatMap(({ colours = [] }) => colours);

console.log(colours);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const val1 = this.testUsers.map((value) => value.colours) // [undefined, undefined, ['green', 'blue', red'], ['black', 'blue']]
const val2 = val1.filter((val) => val !== undefined) // [['green', 'blue', red'], ['black', 'blue']]
const output = val2.flatMap(val => val) // ['green', 'blue', red', 'black', 'blue']
```

Comment: Thank you, always great to see how different operators impact what happens with the data :)